# Changing tmux "normal" mouse from fn key to ctrl key

Tags: terminal, keyboard, mouse, tmux

When running tmux in a terminal window, I can get the usual terminal mouse behavior by holding down the `fn` key.

When using an external keyboard, I do not have a `fn` key.  How can I map this behavior to another key, such as `ctrl`?